# jQuery Post non working

Tags: php, jquery, post

I'm trying to send via javascript some variables to a php file which will store them in a db. However nothing happens and I don't find my mistake. I am sure that the variables are initizialised in javascript and they are not in php (cause the php code write an empty log).
Can you help me? Thanks a lot

Javascript code:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function returned(data) {
            alert(data);
        }

        function postSecret()
        {

            ....

            alert(v_text + "\n" + v_age + "\n" + v_is_male);

            jQuery.post( "http://localhost:8080/libs/post.php", { text: v_text, age: v_age, is_male: v_is_male },  returned(data), "json");
        }
    </script>
```

Post.php:

```
<?php

    printf("dkls");

    $file = 'log.txt';
    $content .= "session: ".$_POST['text']."  ||  ".$_POST['is_male']."  ||  ".$_POST['age']."\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    ... database...

?>
```

Comment: What do you get when you do a var_dump($_POST) on the post.php page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference the function, not call it (adding the parentheses will evaluate the function and return the result).

The data is passed automagically:

```
function returned(data) {
    alert(data);
}

function postSecret() {
   var data = { text: v_text, age: v_age, is_male: v_is_male };
   jQuery.post( "http://localhost:8080/libs/post.php", data, returned, "json");
                             //                     no parentheses  ^^
}
```

Also, you can't start a variable by adding to it

```
$content .= 
// change to 
$content =
```

Comment: Oh poor me! So exhausted :) Thank you a lot man! In 7 minutes I ll be able to set your post as answer :)